# implement camaraview of CWAC-camera2 in my application

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

As I can implement camaraview of CWAC-camera2 in my application that has another interface?

To implement the cameraview and obtain the resulting bitmap photo

Comment: There is no library named CWAC-camera2. There is [the original CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) and the replacement [CWAC-Cam2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2). If by "CWAC-camera2", you mean CWAC-Cam2, then you cannot change the user interface of the picture-taking and video-recording activities.

Comment: exact is CWAC-cam2 , what I want is to use the camera and its methods in my interface, it is possible? thanks commonsware

Answer (score 1):

> what I want is to use the camera and its methods in my interface

If by "my interface", you mean your user interface (UI), then that is not supported. The code is open source, and you are welcome to use it however you want, but I am not supporting alternative UIs at this time, or any time soon.