# how to use the camera-cam camera refresh CWAC

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Friends, two questions

1) As i can have refresh my camera to show me the front after applying the builder.useFrontFacingCamera (true); in CWAC-cam (switch back-facing cam)(Note: I mean the first version of CWAC-cam not of CWAC-CAM2)

2) As I can include cameraview of CWAC-cam2 in interface my project

many thanks thanks friends!

Comment: "As i can have refresh my camera to show me the front after applying the builder.useFrontFacingCamera (true); in CWAC-cam (switch back-facing cam)(Note: I mean the first version of CWAC-cam not of CWAC-CAM2)" -- I do not understand what this means, sorry. "As I can include cameraview of CWAC-cam2 in interface my project" -- the only supported API for CWAC-Cam2 is to use the existing activities. This was covered in my answer to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276451/implement-camaraview-of-cwac-camera2-in-my-application).

Comment: dude, I refresh the camera to change the cam back-front cam?

Comment: Again, I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. If you are asking how to support both the front camera and the back camera, use separate `CameraFragment` instances -- you can see this in the demo app.